# What law governs providing online services

Tags: international, online

I have a following question. Let’s say I want to provide a service of fitness coaching. In my country(Czech Republic) to do so, you must have a certificate issued by the Ministry of Education, before you can start the business. So far so good no issue there. But let’s say I want to provide the service online. At that point I still present myself as fitness coach, but if I get a client from another country, what if I don’t meet the qualifications In his country of origin?

And further more. I have the business registered in Czech Republic but I am traveling to a different country. Therefore at that moment I am providing the online services (let’s say an online session) I might be physically in a country that I do not have the legal qualification to provide the services.

And the worst case scenario, what if the both of us(me and the client) are in the same country? And the only thing that connect me to the country I have license to provide the service is the business I “bill” the client through?  Is any of this an issue?